How do I return the value in a column that closest matches another column in Power Query
I am trying to calculate the closest value to the Expected column based on 3 other columns (Week 1, Week 2, Week 3) of data in Power Query



Client
Expected
Week 1
Week 2
Week 3
Closest




Client 1
153
153
148
148
?


Client 2
3479
3464
3263
3310
?


Client 3
2951
2965
3211
3220
?



Normally, I use this Index/Match formula in a table:
=INDEX(Data[@[Week 1]:[Week 3]],MATCH(MIN(ABS(Data[@[Week 1]:[Week 3]-[@Expected])),ABS(ABS(Data[@[Week 1]:[Week 3]-[@Expected]),0))
I am trying to find the equivalent formula for Power Query and googling has left me empty and frustrated.
I have tried calculating a column
=Number.Abs(List.Min({[Week 1],[Week 2],[Week 3]})-[Expected])
to get the smallest difference but I am not sure how to take the next step and select the value in the column that has the smallest difference.

You need to calculate the absolute differences for Week 1 Week 2 and Week 3 compared to Expected and extract the smallest value from the DifferenceList.
Then you find the week value that matches the MinimumDifference and you can
remove the DifferenceList and MinimumDifference columns.
    let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wcs7JTM0rUTBU0lEyNDVGkCYWUDJWB67ICChkbGJuCabMTECUkRlItbGxoQGyQpCYkaWpIZgyMwUrNDQEU0ZAhbEA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Client = _t, Expected = _t, #"Week 1" = _t, #"Week 2" = _t, #"Week 3" = _t]),
    #"Type modifié" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Client", type text}, {"Expected", Int64.Type}, {"Week 1", Int64.Type}, {"Week 2", Int64.Type}, {"Week 3", Int64.Type}}),

    #"Add Difference List" = Table.AddColumn(#"Type modifié", "DifferenceList", each {Number.Abs([#"Week 1"] - [Expected]), Number.Abs([#"Week 2"] - [Expected]), Number.Abs([#"Week 3"] - [Expected])}),

    #"Add Minimum Difference" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Difference List", "MinimumDifference", each List.Min([DifferenceList])),

    #"Add Closest Value" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Minimum Difference", "Closest", each List.First(List.Select({[#"Week 1"], [#"Week 2"], [#"Week 3"]}, (x) => Number.Abs(x - [Expected]) = [MinimumDifference]))),

    #"Removed Extra Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Closest Value",{"DifferenceList", "MinimumDifference"})
in
    #"Removed Extra Columns"



Here is one way to do it.
It mimics the Index/Match method you use in Excel.
This uses the Advanced Editor.
  Assumes the Week Columns  are all the columns from column 3 to the end of the table, although you could name them specifically, as shown in the second code example below.
let

//Change Source to reflect actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Client", type text}, {"Expected", Int64.Type}, {"Week 1", Int64.Type}, {"Week 2", Int64.Type}, {"Week 3", Int64.Type}}),
    
    #"Add Closest" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Closest",(r)=> 
        let 
            wkValues = List.Skip(Record.FieldValues(r),2),
            Differences = List.Transform(wkValues, each Number.Abs(_ - r[Expected])),
            position = List.PositionOf(Differences, List.Min(Differences))
        in 
            wkValues{position}, Int64.Type)
in
    #"Add Closest"


If you were just using the User Interface, you could

Add a Custom Column

=let 
  wkValues = {[Week 1],[Week 2],[Week 3]},
  Differences = List.Transform(wkValues, (L)=> Number.Abs(L - [Expected])),
  position = List.PositionOf(Differences, List.Min(Differences))
  in wkValues{position}


And then set the data type to Whole Number.

Simple enough,
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wcs7JTM0rUTBU0lEyNDVGkCYWUDJWB67ICChkbGJuCabMTECUkRlItbGxoQGyQpCYkaWpIZgyMwUrNDQEU0ZAhbEA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Client = _t, Expected = _t, #"Week 1" = _t, #"Week 2" = _t, #"Week 3" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Client", type text}, {"Expected", Int64.Type}, {"Week 1", Int64.Type}, {"Week 2", Int64.Type}, {"Week 3", Int64.Type}}),

    #"Added Column Closest" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Closest", (r) => List.Min(List.Skip(Record.ToList(r), 2), null, each Number.Abs(_-r[Expected])))
in
    #"Added Column Closest"


